# Django: how to import static files dynamically from context variable?

Tags: python, django

I have a variable in my context called `THEME`. According to its value, django should load CSS files from one folder or another.

This is how I've defined my context processor to read the variable `THEME` form the settings file:

```
from django.conf import settings

def theme(request):
    return {'theme': getattr(settings, "THEME", None)}
```

I'm trying to build the css path dynamically like this:

```
        {% with 'myapp/css/'|add:THEME|add:'.custom_theme.css' as image_static %}
          {% static image_static %}
        {% endwith %}
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /foo/bar/

Failed lookup for key [THEME] in u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}, {}, ...
```

I try another way:

```
        {% with 'myapp/css/'|add:request.THEME|add:'.custom_theme.css' as image_static %}
          {% static image_static %}
        {% endwith %}
```

And I get this error:

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /foo/bar/

Failed lookup for key [THEME] in u"<WSGIRequest: GET '/foo/bar/'>"
```

Any idea on how can I build the load static path to the CSS dynamically based on the value of my context variable "THEME"?

Comment: What do you see if you just output {{ THEME }} in your template? UPDATE: Shouldn't it be "theme" instead of "THEME"?

Comment: Are you sure that that context processor is being run? It doesn't seem to be. I must say though that this would be much nicer as a simple template tag, rather than gluing together a whole bunch of strings and context variables in the template.

Answer (score 1):

You set the context variable "theme" (lowercase):

```
def theme(request):
    return {'theme': getattr(settings, "THEME", None)}
```

But you're looking for the variable "THEME" (uppercase):

```
Failed lookup for key [THEME]
```

And as Daniel suggest (was about to do the same): write your own templatetag instead. Should take about two or three lines...

Comment: Thanks (and thanks Jonas who spotted it about the same time) - but really do yourself and whoever will have to maintain your code a favour and write your own template tag instead.